# Jquery / Javascript onclick event to html open select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span that I have positioned on top of a select tag, when you click on the select tag the menu opens to select a value, but when you click on the span positioned on top of the select tag nothing happens. Is there an jquery way to use on click that will open the select tag menu?

```
<select id="support_support_type" name="support[support_type]">
  <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
  <option value="Feedback">Feedback</option>
  <option value="Help">Help</option>
</select>
<span class="drop down-arrow"></span>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is the span `position`ed `absolute` over the select box? If so, it's a lot more convenient to use CSS' pointer-events for that. Given that [it's compatible with almost all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), I would use it for production. CSS rules generally are also preferred over javascript hackery.

Add this to your CSS file and you'll be good to go.

```
.drop.down-arrow{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

What that does is basically allows the cursor to click through it to the `<select>` under it. Hope I was helpful!

Comment: Elegent solution, however I'm using hover etc to render styles on the selector. :/

Answer (score 3):

You want to trigger the click event of `select` tag when you click on the span. So set up a jquery function like this:

```
$('span').click(function() {
    var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    e.initMouseEvent('mousedown');
    $('select')[0].dispatchEvent(e);
});
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5op3cxmp/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.attr()` and set it to show/hide the avilable options.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var toggle = true;
$("span.down-arrow").on("click", function(){
  if(toggle){
    $("select#support_support_type").attr('size', 3); // show all 3 options
    toggle = false;
  }
  else{
    $("select#support_support_type").attr('size', 1); // show only the selected option
    toggle = true;
  }
});

$('select#support_support_type').on("change", function() {
  $(this).attr('size', 1); 
  toggle = true;
});
```

```css
span{
  vertical-align: top;
}

select{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="support_support_type" name="support[support_type]">
  <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
  <option value="Feedback">Feedback</option>
  <option value="Help">Help</option>
</select>

<span class="drop down-arrow">span</span>
```

Readup:

- [`.attr()` | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: could I add this inline using <span class="drop down-arrow" onclick=""></span>?

Comment: @trying_hal9000 Yes, you can do that. By the way, I have updated my answer with the code and a working code snippet.

Comment: @trying_hal9000 To achieve what you are trying to do, you need to make appropriate changes in the JS.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want is the functionality that labels offer. So, you would be better off using `<label>`, instead of binding.

```
<label for="support_support_type">Select</label>
<select id="support_support_type" name="support[support_type]">
   <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
   <option value="Feedback">Feedback</option>
   <option value="Help">Help</option>
</select>
```

Now, you've what `<span>` does, that is display the text, but when you click on it, the `<select>` would automatically get focused.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, I tried changing the span into a label and using relative position put it on top of the select tag, but the drop down does not appear when it's clicked